# Seleccionar todos los elementos impares, pero nth-of-type(odd) no ayuda

Tags: html, css, html5

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en el que tengo que colorear todos los artículos impares de un color y los pares de otro.

Como tengo cada artículo separado por `section`, he implementado en CSS lo siguiente:

```
section:nth-of-type(odd){
   background: #DBDBDB;
}

section:nth-of-type(even){
   background: #33C9FF;
}
```

Pero el único que me funciona es el (even) coloreando todo del color especificado en este.

PD: Perdonadme, antes he puesto even dos veces, pero fue al estar trasteando con él dado el error. Lo he corregido varias veces y sigue sin ir.

Siento la tardanza he estado trasteando con el código y al parecer, como ya han comentado algunos he tenido errores en el html. Siento el lío, y gracias por la aportación a todos.

Comment: En tu código se duplica `nth-of-type(even)`. Creo que querías hacer uno de ellos el `nth-of-type(odd)`.

Comment: Sugiero que cambies `:nth-of-type()` por `:nth-child()`.

Comment: @EdgarGutiérrez ¿por qué? ¿qué cambiaría? ¿qué regla se aplicaría con `nth-child()` que no se aplique con `nth-of-type()`? Además, ya hay una respuesta con esto mismo.

Comment: Hola @Pavl. ¿Podrías publicar el HTML que reproduce el caso donde no se apliquen bien las reglas? La idea es que todas las preguntas tengan un [mcve].

Comment: Y tienes toda la razón, @Mariano en principio las dos deberían funcionar, estuve buscando en la fuente oficial, la [w3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-of-type) para ver si era un valor no permitido en ese selector y resulta que sí lo es, por lo tanto parece ser que los `section` no los esta colocando contigüos unos con otros , sino que hay un elemento entre ambos u otra razón, para confirmar sería bueno que @pavl nos coloque, como sugieres, el `html` de la estructura que esta usando. Saludos.

Comment: @Edgar en el caso de que haya elementos intermedios, `nth-of-type()` funcionaría bien, y `nth-child()` no (al contrario de tu comentario anterior)

Comment: Yo he probado tu ejemplo y funciona perfectamente... https://jsfiddle.net/9zy7kcj0/. Deberías agregar tu código HTML ya que ahora la pregunta se puede cerrar como no reproducible...

Comment: Votando por cerrar como *no reproducible*, ya que la respuesta aceptada utiliza el mismo código que la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con nth-child(even) y nth-child(odd) de la siguiente manera:

```css
section:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
section:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

```html
<section>  1 </section>
<section>  2 </section>
<section>  3 </section>
<section>  4 </section>
```

EDITADO:

Probando el código con nth-of-type:

```css
section:nth-of-type(odd){
   background: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(even){
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>  1 </section>
<section>  2 </section>
<section>  3 </section>
<section>  4 </section>
```

Ambas pruebas si funcionan...
Quizá sea la forma en la que estás colocando el HTML.

Saludos.

Comment: No veo ninguna diferencia con `nth-of-type()`. ¿Por qué `nth-child()` funcionaría en un caso que `nth-of-type()` no?

Comment: Tienes razón, acabo de verificar que con ambos tipos funciona, supongo que es la forma en la cuál estás colocando el HTML, recuerda poner un 
 ejemplo según https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

> La pseudo-clase CSS :nth-of-type(an+b) selecciona, en el árbol del
>   documento, el elemento que tiene an+b-1 hermanos con el mismo nombre
>   de elemento situados antes que él, para un n con valor positivo o
>   cero, y que tiene un elemento padre. Ver :nth-child para una
>   descripción más detallada de la sintaxis de los argumentos de esta
>   pseudo-clase. :nth-of-type(an+b) es un pseudo-selector más flexible y
>   útil si quiere asegurarse de seleccionar el mismo tipo de etiqueta,
>   sin importar donde está situada dentro de su elemento padre, o que
>   otro tipo de etiquetas aparecen antes de ella.

[Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Ademas:

> El selector n-ésimo ( n ) coincide con cada elemento que es el n-
>   ésimo hijo, de un tipo particular, de su padre.
>
> n puede ser un número, una palabra clave o una fórmula.
>
> Consejo: Observe el selector : nth-child () para seleccionar el
>   elemento que es el n- ésimo hijo, independientemente del tipo , de su
>   elemento primario.

```css
section:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: #444444;
    color: #fff;
}

section:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<body>

<section>Primera seccion.</section>
<section>Segunda seccion</section>
<section>Tercera seccion</section>
<section>Cuarta seccion</section>

</body>
```

PD: Quiza no funcione porque estas usando los selectores(HTML)

Comment: ¿Y por qué funciona? ¿Cuál es la diferencia? La idea de las respuestas es que tengan una descripción de la solución implementada.... Asumo que fue sólo el descuido del autor al usar 2 veces `even`, pero sería bueno leerlo en tu respuesta